# ack-grep: chars escaping

Tags: perl, unix, grep, ack

My goal is to find all "`<?=`" occurrences with ack. How can I do that?

```
ack "<?="
```

Doesn't work. Please tell me how can I fix escaping here?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Since `ack` uses Perl regular expressions, your problem stems from the fact that in Perl RegEx language, `?` is a special character meaning "last match is optional". So what you are grepping for is `=` preceded by an optional `<`

So you need to escape the `?` if that's just meant to be a regular character.

To escape, there are two approaches - either `<\?=` or `<[?]=`; some people find the second form of escaping (putting a special character into a character class) more readable than backslash-escape.

**UPDATE** As Josh Kelley graciously added in the comment, a third form of escaping is to use the `\Q` operator which escapes all the following special characters till `\E` is encountered, as follows: `\Q<?=\E`

Comment: Or use `\Q<?=\E` to escape ALL special characters.

Comment: Or use the -Q option to escape all special characters, too, because really, who wants to mess with the \Q \E crap?

Answer (score 20):

Rather than trying to remember which characters have to be escaped, you can use -Q to quote everything that needs to be quoted.

Answer (score 15):

```
ack -Q "<?="
```

This is the best solution if you will want to find by simple text.

(if you need not find by regular expression.)

Answer (score 8):

```
ack "<\?="
```

? is a regex operator, so it needs escaping