# How to search for '<' in files using ack in powershell in windows?

Tags: windows, powershell, escaping, ack

I cannot figure out how to escape the '<' character, and I am confused by the 'The system cannot find the file specified' error.  Can anyone help?

I am using ack in powershell in Windows XP.

The question [ack-grep: chars escaping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3074122/ack-grep-please-help-with-chars-escaping) is very similar to mine, but the solutions offered and accepted for that question do not work for me.

```
PS C:\xampp\htdocs> ack abcd
<works as expected>
PS C:\xampp\htdocs> ack <
The redirection operator '<' is not supported yet.
At line:1 char:5
+ ack < <<<<
PS C:\xampp\htdocs> ack \<
The syntax of the command is incorrect.
PS C:\xampp\htdocs> ack '<'
The syntax of the command is incorrect.
PS C:\xampp\htdocs> ack '\<'
The syntax of the command is incorrect.
PS C:\xampp\htdocs> ack [<]
The system cannot find the file specified.
PS C:\xampp\htdocs> ack '[<]'
The system cannot find the file specified.
PS C:\xampp\htdocs> ack '[\<]'
The system cannot find the file specified.
PS C:\xampp\htdocs> ack \Q<\E
The system cannot find the file specified.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is there any reason you don't want to use PowerShell's regex search?

```
Select-String '<' *.*

## or
dir -r | Select-String '<'
```

Comment: I did not know that feature existed.  Thanks for notifying me of it.  The second command you suggested has solved my problem.

Comment: Is there a good resource for performance comparison between this tool and Unix ones (ack, ag, ripgrep, grep) ?

Answer (score 0):

Escape character in PowerShell is backtick:

```
PS C:\xampp\htdocs> ack `<
```

Comment: The problem is not PowerShell, the problem is on the ack or shell side.

Comment: When I type "ack \`<" I get the error "The syntax of the command is incorrect".  Stej, can you confirm that you have run the command 'ack `<' on your system and that it works for you?  If so I'll agree with JasonMArcher.

Answer (score -1):

<strike>Do you mean `awk`? If so, then all you have to do is:  $`awk '/</ filename'`</strike>

Since I don't have ack installed I can't verify 100%, but I would try this code out:

```
ack  '<' --output '$1' -h
```

If that doesn't work, then I would recommend reading through the `man ack` and the `ack --help` pages.

Comment: I have edited the question to show the output when attempting 'ack <'.

Comment: @Tom I've updated my answer. Hopefully you will find it useful.

Comment: Thanks for you help Moses, but when I type "ack '<' --output '$i' -h" I get the error "The system cannot find the file specified."