# how to stop shell script from getting confused by ack PATTERN escapes

Tags: bash, ack

I am trying to use ack to search (in Haskell files) for  +|+

I looked at [ack-grep: chars escaping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3074122/ack-grep-chars-escaping)
but this doesn't help

On Mac OS X 10.6 I get the following responses:

```
$ ack -Q +|+
-bash: +: command not found
Missing option after +
ack: See ack --help, ack --help-types or ack --man for options

$ ack \+\|\+
Unknown option: |
ack: See ack --help, ack --help-types or ack --man for options

$ ack [+][|][+]
-bash: ][+]: command not found
ack: Invalid regex '[+][':
  Unmatched [ in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/[+][ <-- HERE /

$ ack \Q+|+\E
-bash: +E: command not found
```

That's basically all the suggestions in the Q&A listed above

Comment: The problem here is that you're dealing with two levels of escaping, first `bash` and then `ack` itself. Try putting quotes around the arguments to get them past `bash` then apply the tips in your linked question for `ack`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work as intended:

```
$ ack "\+\|\+"
```

(Edited to be correct per your comments. Unquoted pipe is 'or'.)

Comment: It runs for me, but it matches + ++  whereas I want to match +|+ precisely.

Comment: I tried escaping the | using "\+\|\+"  - that worked - thanks

Comment: I've just realised that quotes appeared in the other question I cited above - but not the answers - hence my missing the answer staring me in the face....

Comment: Thanks for the correction, I edited the answer to be correct so it's not confusing for anyone else later.

Answer (score 0):

The `-Q` will quote everything in your search string.

```
ack --haskell -Q '+|+'
```

which is easier than

```
ack --haskell "\+\|\+"
```